# Derive a column value in parent groups using values from child groups in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm tracking active and deactive counts for 3 months(**child group**) based on acquisition month(**parent group**)

My Matrix design
[image]

Preview 
[image]

I want to calculate 2nd month deact rate (see picture for formula used)

I know about variables but how can i use child variables in parent group ?
or is there any other way to achieve that 2nd month deact value ?

Comment: I would do this in SQL and pass the results to the report, there may be a way to do this in SSRS but I don't think so...

Comment: I was able to do that in SQL but there are some rows Eg: subtotals (group total) where  SQL Doesn't help

Comment: Show what you have tried otherwise people will waste time  suggesting options you have already exhausted.

Comment: I calculated the values using SQL and stored it my reporting table (did that for totals and subtotals also and used that column  in SSRS which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way is to calculate the required values by self joining (in my case ) reporting table and also have dedicated column for total for groups and use those columns in SSRS.